# Application stopped working after frequent http calls from client to server leading to huge number of time_wait states in sockets

Tags: java, sockets

In my scenario i ran a script which schedules files repeatedly,my application do some computations and sends response to client ie client is making a repetitive http call to get the response of each file.When around 150 files are scheduled socket ports in my server goes in time_wait state and their count exceeds thousands and an exception is thrown in client which opens a http connection ie

```
 Error : [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

The result was that my application hanged.I do not know may be threads have gone in wait state or what has happened but i need to kill all processes or restart my application to make it work again.

I tried reducing wait time to 30 seconds since it is 240 seconds by default but it did not work.

Is there any way i can reuse those ports that are gone in wait state?

Would this property make any difference if i add it in client code when it opens a http connection?

```
http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).MaxIdleConnsPerHost = numCoroutines
```

took reference from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803566/what-is-the-cost-of-many-time-wait-on-the-server-side/39205602?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Have very less idea about sockets.Please guide!!