# Can I close file descriptors for currently unused UIAppFonts?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, file-descriptor, uifont, uiappfonts

We bundle a lot of fonts with our iOS app, and we put them all in `UIAppFonts` for faster loading.
(We're using them inside `UIWebView` and it's *much* faster than using loading files with `@font-face`).

However this lead me to occasionally get this kind of warning:

```
Mar 13 23:07:16 iPad afcd[2582] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Mar 13 23:07:17 iPad mobile_house_arrest[2584] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Mar 13 23:07:17 iPad mobile_house_arrest[2586] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Mar 13 23:07:17 iPad mobile_house_arrest[2587] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Mar 13 23:07:17 iPad mobile_house_arrest[2588] <Error>: Max open files: 78
```

This also correlated with I/O exceptions when opening files.

I used [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8153026/458193) to find out the leaking files and it looks like iOS  **keeps open file descriptors for every font listed in `UIAppFonts` throughout the whole lifetime of the application**.

```
File Descriptor 8 number 9 in use for: Fonts/ABeeZee-Regular.ttf
File Descriptor 9 number 10 in use for: Fonts/ABeeZee-Regular.ttf
File Descriptor 10 number 11 in use for: Fonts/ABeeZee-Italic.ttf
File Descriptor 11 number 12 in use for: Fonts/ABeeZee-Italic.ttf
File Descriptor 12 number 13 in use for: Fonts/AmaticSC-Regular.ttf
File Descriptor 13 number 14 in use for: Fonts/AmaticSC-Regular.ttf
File Descriptor 14 number 15 in use for: Fonts/AmaticSC-Bold.ttf
File Descriptor 15 number 16 in use for: Fonts/AmaticSC-Bold.ttf
File Descriptor 16 number 17 in use for: Fonts/AnonymousPro-Bold.ttf
File Descriptor 17 number 18 in use for: Fonts/AnonymousPro-Bold.ttf
File Descriptor 18 number 19 in use for: Fonts/AnonymousPro-Regular.ttf
File Descriptor 19 number 20 in use for: Fonts/AnonymousPro-Regular.ttf
```

For us, it means about a hundred open file descriptors, although not more than five of `UIAppFonts` are being used at the moment. Sometimes, duplicate entries show up.

**Is there anyway to forcibly close file descriptors for `UIAppFonts` I'm not using at the moment?**

If not, is there an alternative way of keeping local fonts available to `UIWebView` without resorting to `@font-face` which is slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If not, is there an alternative way of keeping local fonts available to UIWebView without resorting to @font-face which is slow?

Turns out, there is.

We solved the problem by registering fonts using [`CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_FontManager_Ref/Reference/reference.html) and unregistering them with [`CTFontManagerUnregisterFontsForURL`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_FontManager_Ref/Reference/reference.html). This keeps them available for `UIWebView`, given that you always register fonts before using them in `font-family`.

Comment: Came across this issue now in an app with 120+ custom fonts. Not using UIWebView though, just custom UILabels... Guess it's time to cut down on the font list...

Comment: @Brad: I presume this method should work for UILabels as well. (Unless you need to display all 120+ of them at once)

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with closing file descriptors associated with a Sprite Kit action,

```
playSoundFileNamed:
```

They never close.  So they eat up file descriptors until the app crashes.  I figured out a way to close them.  I don't see why it wouldn't work for your UIAppFonts.

I modified the snippet you referenced in your question.  This is my modified version,

```
#import <sys/types.h>
#import <fcntl.h>
#import <errno.h>
#import <sys/param.h>


-(void)closeFileDescriptorsForSounds
{
    int flags;
    int fd;
    char buf[MAXPATHLEN+1] ;
    int n = 1 ;

    for (fd = 0; fd < (int) FD_SETSIZE; fd++) {
        errno = 0;
        flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD, 0);
        if (flags == -1 && errno) {
            if (errno != EBADF) {
                return ;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
        fcntl(fd , F_GETPATH, buf ) ;
        NSLog( @"File Descriptor %d number %d in use for: %s",fd,n , buf ) ;
        ++n ;

// My modifications to the snippet...

        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf];
        NSString *theFileName = [str lastPathComponent];

        if ([theFileName isEqualToString:@"LoudBang.mp3"])
        {
            NSLog(@"FD is LoudBang");
            NSFileHandle *loudBangHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fd closeOnDealloc:YES];
        }
        else if ([theFileName isEqualToString:@"QuietBang.mp3"])
        {
            NSLog(@"FD is QuietBang");
            NSFileHandle *quietBangHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fd closeOnDealloc:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

I converted buf to a string and then isolated the file name.  Then I compared the file name to a known file I want to close.  When a file I want to close is found the code creates an NSFileHandle around the file descriptor using the following,

```
NSFileHandle *loudBangHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fd closeOnDealloc:YES];
```

This init specifically closes the file descriptor on dealloc of the NSFileHandle (which will be almost immediately).

Let us know if it works for your UIAppFonts.