# Italic Font Is Not Working on XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts

I have copy my ttf font (ABeeZee-Italic.ttf) from Google WebFonts into Supporting Files and added into plist :

[image]

and assign my Label with tag = 4 :

[image]

because I have this code to embed fonts into UILabel:

```
for (UILabel *customLabel in [[self view] subviews]) {
    if (customLabel.tag == 1) {
        [customLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-ExtraLight" size:21]];
    } else if (customLabel.tag==2){
        [customLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ABeeZee-Regular" size:14]];
    } else if (customLabel.tag==3){
        [customLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ABeeZee-Regular" size:11]];
    } else if (customLabel.tag==4){
        [customLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ABeeZee-Italic" size:12]];
    }
}
```

it's all working like a charm, but the italic font is not loaded into my iPod (iOS 6.1.3). UILabel with tag 4 is the iOS system font. not ABeeZee-Italic.

I tried to change the tag number, but also failed. Is there any specific requirements for non-regular font to be embedded into iOS?

thank you

UPDATE @iPatel answer : here's how my FontBook looks like, it has same name... 
[image]

Comment: dont use tags as they are mess to maintain.. and use `UIFont familyNames` to find the font name for the italic font

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255141/uifont-fontwithname-returns-nil ?

Comment: Please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037091/custom-font-not-working-in-ios-5/17037402#17037402

Comment: Did you add the ttf to the resource bundle? (File inspector, checkmark next to target)

Comment: @RobvanderVeer : yes I did.

Answer (score 1):

Check what is real name of font *(ABeeZee-Italic)* in "FontBook" ? and write name of font which is in "FontBook".

And use such like

```
[myLabelName  setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Font Name From Font Book" size:32]];
```

More information about how to add custom font in app. then read [This Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597905/uifont-impact-not-working-for-ios/15597986#15597986)

**EDITED:**

Also try with

- Select Your font from your project
- right click
- Open With External Editor
- Install Font
- select inserted font
- And check what is **"Full name"**, copy and past it in your code:

May be helpful :)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I already put screenshot on my post, please kindly check my screenshot above

Comment: I tried to use "ABeeZee-Italic", "ABeeZee Italic" (with space) and "ABeeZeeItalic" (without space) but still none of them is working... :-(

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways.

**Using ttf file**

```
[customLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-ExtraLight.ttf" size:21]];
```

or

**Using font name**

```
[customLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:<Name of Raleway-ExtraLight> size:21]];
```

In your case just add **.ttf** in `setFont:` else get Name of font as shown in below image.

Just right click on .ttf file > Get Info > Full Name (your font name. You can use this name as font name in setFont)

[image]

**EDIT**

Check the full name here and paste it in your code.

```
[customLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ABeeZee Italic" size:21]];
```

**EDIT 1**

May be you need to [Register Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397573/can-i-close-file-descriptors-for-currently-unused-uiappfonts). Just try to register and check.

Comment: @Robert Hanson Try to add .ttf extension in your existing code and test once.

Comment: I did this "ABeeZee-Italic.ttf" but still no luck... It's really strange... I have no problem with the other font, but this one...

Comment: @RobertHanson use font name as "ABeeZee Italic" and test once.