# Custom font not showing up

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I tried to modify a UILabel with a custom font, and it works if I use `BPREPLAY` instead of `BPREPLAYITALICS`

Both custom fonts are added the same way inside the project and are declared in the info.plist in `Fonts provided by Application`:

[image]

```
[_all setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"BPREPLAYITALICS" size:37.5]];
_all.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(170/255.0) green:(170/255.0) blue:(170/255.0) alpha:1] ;
_all.text = @"All";
```

Now, when I use the Italics font it does only show the font I used in the storyboard, unlike with the other font style.

Comment: did you check BPREPLAYITALICS.OTF is added to your target. ?

Comment: @Priyatham51 yes it is, just like the other one

Comment: did you check here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798560/italic-font-is-not-working-on-xcode

Comment: @Priyatham51 great, thanks a lot. I didnt see it before, works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got it working now, credits go to

[Italic Font Is Not Working on XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798560/italic-font-is-not-working-on-xcode)

I had to look into the full file-name. The solution was to use

`UIFont fontWithName:@"BPreplay-Italic"` which I found in the information about the file itself.