# Writing to hard disk Error - Too many open files

Tags: xamarin.ios

During some process, I'm storing objects to a file (serialization). Each batch will store 100 files. I'm quickly getting "Too many open files" error.

I'm closing the StreamWriter immediately after usage and I also tried to dispose the file. I'm having a multithread application, but I centralised the storage into a single thread to make sure that there are no more then X operations in parallel. I'm now even storing object by object (one at a time) and i'm still getting this error.

It looks like "closing" or "disposing" the StreamWriter is not enough. Any idea someone?

I tried a lot of different code, but this is my current code:

```
            Log.i("Streamwriter opened");
            StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter (filePath);
            outfile.Write (content);
            outfile.Close ();
            outfile.Dispose ();
            Log.i("Streamwriter closed");
```

I printed it also out to make sure that "opening" a file is always immediatly followed by "closing" a file.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd guess that the GC is not able to keep up with the number of files you're creating.  You might try switching to SGen to see if that helps - http://www.mono-project.com/Working_With_SGen

Comment: My guess is that there are other open files. You should be able to use Instruments and one of the file-related templates to view disk activity and see which file is being kept open.

Comment: Switching GC, as suggested by @Jason, won't help - that's why using `IDisposable` is the *right* thing to do. Something else is likely using too many files (like @Rolf said). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15886034/220643 and links for a bit more information.

Comment: Even if you're centralizing it: how do you prevent that 100 calls to your logging happen at the same time? Is there a `lock()` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Any reason you're not using, well, using: "using (var ourfile = new StreamWriter(filePath) {}"?

Comment: @Skall: I was using a "using" block. Just out of desperation, I tried to manually dispose it.

Comment: @Krumelur: there is indeed a "lock" in my code (before calling this function to save data to the HD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already tried Instruments and I/O templates before posting this question, but couldn't find anything strange there. I now tried some other methods from following link: [on iOS/iPhone: "Too many open files": need to list open files (like lsof)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083608/on-ios-iphone-too-many-open-files-need-to-list-open-files-like-lsof) (the link was posted in the stackoverflow thread posted by poupou in his comment)

The best method for me was just to type in **"lsof" in Terminal**. I immediately saw that there were **a lot of open files of my database**.
Before serialisation, I also write the ID of the object to my database. Because the error "Too many open files" always pointed to my serialisation code (and not my database code), I was looking there for a problem.

When inserting an object into my database, I'm using "SqliteConnection". I was correctly closing AND disposing this object, however, it seems this is not enough to really also close my database file.

This URL was helpful to me: [SQLite keeps the database locked even after the connection is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532729/sqlite-keeps-the-database-locked-even-after-the-connection-is-closed)

**I** indeed **did not dispose the "SqliteCommand"** itself.

After fixing this, I do not receive this error anymore.

***Thanks!***

```
    SqliteConnection cnn = new SqliteConnection(dbConnection);
    cnn.Open();
    SqliteCommand mycommand = new SqliteCommand(cnn);
    mycommand.CommandText = sql;
    object value = mycommand.ExecuteScalar();
    mycommand.Dispose ();     // <= THIS FIXED THE ERROR
    cnn.Close();
    cnn.Dispose ();
```

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense than the StreamWriter. Also a good demonstration why 'using' is preferred when you need to dispose the object on the same scope. Makes it easier to read (in my opinion) as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hope that will fix that strange error in my application, too. As SKall said, you should always use an using block around disposable objects: http://www.dotnetperls.com/using

(I can't actually in my special case, because I am collection SqliteCommands within a unit of work session, so I am now disposing them after committing the session).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FileSystemWatcher it can be the reason of the problem: [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534828/system-io-ioexception-too-many-open-files)

When we disabled FileSystemWatcher in our project the error disappeared (we experienced the same error for Xamarin.Mac though, but probably it's relevant for Xamarin.iOS too).