# System.IO.IOException: Too many open files

Tags: macos, servicestack, xamarin-studio

I'm getting this error intermittently when debugging my ServiceStack web app on Mac OS X.

I can't seem to pinpoint what it is, I've tried killing the xamarin web server by using this command:

```
ps aux | grep xsp4 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

I've tried renewing my DHCP lease and clearing my DNS cache.
Even tried restarting the entire Mac.

Mind you there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code, because when I run the Xamarin web server manually with this command:

```
xsp4 --root ~/Development/PROJ_FOLDER --port 8080
```

it works fine...
I only see the issue when I run the application from Xamarin Studio.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved a similar issue by disabling Mono's file watcher [due to a bug](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2118#issuecomment-77169959).

In the terminal:

```
export MONO_MANAGED_WATCHER=disabled
```

You might also want to look [here](https://superuser.com/a/443168).

Comment: Avoid link-only answers; they are likely to be closed as low-quality. If the link ever changes/moves, your answer is no longer valid, so it's best to include the relevant information from the links in your answer.

Comment: Since applying this change, I haven't come across the error. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, how can I turn on it again?