# iOS: DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed

Tags: ios, wamp, alamofire

Everything in my app uses either Alamofire or MDWamp.

When the app is on for a longer period of time I get a crazy amount of these errors:

```
<Error>: tcp_connection_host_start 7181 DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: -65537
<Warning>: dnssd_clientstub deliver_request: socketpair failed 24 (Too many open files)
<Error>: tcp_connection_host_start 7182 DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: -65537
<Warning>: dnssd_clientstub deliver_request: socketpair failed 24 (Too many open files)
<Error>: tcp_connection_host_start 7182 DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: -65537
<Warning>: dnssd_clientstub deliver_request: socketpair failed 24 (Too many open files)
<Error>: tcp_connection_host_start 7183 DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: -65537
<Warning>: dnssd_clientstub deliver_request: socketpair failed 24 (Too many open files)
<Error>: tcp_connection_host_start 7183 DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: -65537
```

I'm struggling to reproduce this and I can't find any information elsewhere..
Any hint or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are leaking file descriptors, or just opening too many files, you need to debug that. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8153026/3100083 for a snippet on which files your app has dangling at any point.

Comment: OP, can you please follow @pevasquez' comment's advice and add more debugging information?