# File pool (like Connection Pool)

Tags: java, file-io, pooling

My English is like 3years old baby.

Recently, I made a website with Many File Access.

Unfortunately, My tomcat gave me this following error message

```
Fatal: Socket accept failed
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:61)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:352)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor run
```

This happens when I send request in short time, I guess there too many stream opened for this job.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem.

My Environment are { tomcat 6.0.35, java 1.6.0_31, centos 5 }
Ah, This only happens on Linux;

thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicated [Linux: socket accept - “Too many open files”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/880557/651140)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the limit allocated by the system
`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr`

(last number)

Allocate more if needed

Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Add/change `fs.file-max = xxxxx`

Apply changes `sysctl -p`

Check `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`

You may also have user limits set.

Comment: As I refresh the page It's getting bigger. And I think there my source problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are closing all your streams ?

Comment: Thanks body. It was stream problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that you are exceeding the default maximum number of file descriptor.

Explanation and how to increase the values:

http://honglus.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/tune-max-open-files-parameter-in-linux.html
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/