# Value returned by accept function in socket communication

Tags: c, sockets, file-descriptor

In a Socket communication when a server accepts a connection, it returns a value which is always greater than 0 if the connection is successful.

```
 ConnectedSocket = accept(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&echoClntAddr,(socklen_t*)&clntSock);
```

Consider a client connected to the server and a server with the number 1 assigned.
Then the client gets disconnected, and after some time another client connects.  Will the accept function assign it the number 1 or number 2?

If the accept function will assign number 2, then after how many connections will number 1 be assigned again?

Comment: `accept()` might very well also return `0`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/880557/694576

Comment: Why are you concerned about accept return value uniqueness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accept call returns a file descriptor which will be used for the new connection. From the man page of accept:

> On success, these system calls return a nonnegative integer that is a descriptor for the accepted socket. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately

The accept will never return 1 since it's the file descriptor used for standard output (unless you close this file descriptor programmatically!). As for the second question:

> If accept function will assign number 2 then after how many connections will number 1 again be assigned ?

accept will use the first unused file descriptor in the process table. Thus, it's possible to reuse the same "returned number" (file descriptor) as soon as the related TCP connection has been closed.

Comment: For the same reason `accept()` "normally" does not return `0` or `1` it won't return `2` either, which is used for `stderr`. To state this again: If those three descriptors used for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` (`0`, `1` and `2`) got `close()`d `accept()` might also re-use them.

Comment: I guess you mean 2 is stderr :)

Comment: I'd possibly go as far as saying "the actual value of the file descriptor has no inherent meaning, other than to distinguish one file from another". It is a value that you should consider not keying on and if you do, you must be extremely fastidious in cleaning up whatever data structures you key from the fd.

Comment: I agree, specially when you program start playing with open, close and dup :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you ask about uniqueness of integers returned from `accept`. `accept` returns file descriptor so if we are talking about POSIX OS then POSIX requires:

> The open() function shall return a file descriptor for the named file
>   that is the lowest file descriptor not currently open for that
>   process.

`accept` internally calls `get_unused_fd_flags` which calls `__alloc_fd` to generate new file descriptor, `open` generates FD the same way so everything that applies to `open` regarding FDs applies to `accept`.

So conclusion: file descriptors can be reused and `accept` can return repeated numbers if those file descriptors were closed earlier.