# gradlew doesnt build unless root

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I try to build a gradle android project in a centos 7 server. When I run 
`./gradlew assembleDebug` it says

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not determine a usable local IP for this machine.

And I logged the error with `--stacktrace` which reveals the following log:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine a usable local IP for this machine.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not determine a usable local IP for this machine.
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory.getLocalBindingAddress(InetAddressFactory.java:89)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileLockCommunicator.<init>(FileLockCommunicator.java:38)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.getCommunicator(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:153)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.reservePort(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:145)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:85)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:73)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.OnDemandFileAccess.readFile(OnDemandFileAccess.java:36)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.get(SimpleStateCache.java:47)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.get(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.getAll(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:112)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:127)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:244)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:217)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files (Socket creation failed)
    at java.net.NetworkInterface.getAll(Native Method)
    at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(NetworkInterface.java:343)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses.analyzeNetworkInterfaces(InetAddresses.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses.<init>(InetAddresses.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory.init(InetAddressFactory.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory.getLocalBindingAddress(InetAddressFactory.java:85)
    ... 38 more
```

But, when I run as root user, the build succeeds and I have the apk. The weird issue is, it still fails even if I run the gradlew as `sudo`. Only executing it as root(#) works.

Anyone knows of any solution?

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8583083/2614364) can help

Comment: @BertrandMartel And are the socket limits independent to each user? Since the buid succeeds as root user

Comment: I have the same problem on a running MacOsX 10.13.2 Beta (17C60c), nothing works, no sudo, no su, nothing.

Comment: Same problem on Mac OS 10.3.2